# What if we don't want to use the EXM Module on Sitecore 9?

Tags: exm, sitecore-install-framework

We are configuring Sitecore 9.0.2 in a scaled environment and we don't have plans to use the EXM Module. We know how to disable the EXM module but in that case which all roles can be ignored on Sitecore 9 scaled setup? Do we still need to Roles like Messaging, Marketing Automation, Marketing Automation Reporting etc?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EXM is built into the platform, so other than just disabling it via config, you don't have to do anything else to it.

### EXM Artifacts

You can ignore the following services and configurations if EXM has been disabled in the web.config:

- The Dedicated Dispatch Server role does not need to be installed.
- The EXM.Master database can be removed.
- The EXM.Crypto and EXM.Authentication Keys in the ConnectionStrings.config can be removed.

Everything else should remain. However, I will respond to the other parts you listed.

#### Messaging

The messaging database should be left intact. This database is used for the Rebus message queueing service that is part of the overall Sitecore Framework. While it's true that EXM is the first module to make use of it, future modules will most likely utilize it. I would leave this alone.

#### Marketing Automation

Marketing Automation is a sibling to EXM. It is part of the overall XP services that are offered for marketing campaign initiatives. The engine and reporting services you mention are part of xConnect. Not all of those initiatives utilize email. Leave it and the related xConnect services intact.